# notepad++ : can I add a 2-char delimiter to the list of auto-close brackets?

Tags: notepad++, auto-close

I'd like to mod NP++ so that typing  `/*` brings up the matching `*/` automatically.  The Prefs dialog for bracket matching appears only to allow single-char values for custom auto-close pairs. Can I achieve this w/o diving into some auto-running macro?

Comment: It seems you need to write your own plugin for that. [*Only single characters are allowed in these fields.*](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried -- get the error "MSVCP140D.DLL" missing.  I do not have that DLL on my system.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  I have XbracketsLite installed